# How to prove the uniqueness of the smallest ball containing finite points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, spheres

**Problem.** Let $A$ be a set of finite points in Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$. Let $B$ be the ball containing $A$ with smallest radius. Prove the uniqueness of $B$.

The natural idea is two use contradiction argument, i.e. assume that there exist two smallest balls with same radius and distinct centers. But how do I deduce a contradiction from here? I spent the whole day to think about this but no progress. Thank you for any idea!

**Comment.** I found a paper of [Mordukhovich et. al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.1280.pdf), but they used variational
analysis in their arguments, which is too strong for such a "simple" problem, I think.

Comment: Just an intuition. Since $A$ is finite, we can obtain its convex hull. It seems that such ball $B$ is the one with every point on the convex hull lying on it.

Comment: @BernardPan yeah, your observation is intuitively correct. But I am not sure how to use it (if it is correct) to prove the uniqueness.

Comment: What's the radius of the smallest ball containing $B_1 \cap B_2 \supseteq A$?

Comment: Sorry. I just find a counterexample: a convex pentagon on $\Bbb R^2$ with one diagonal line segment rather long but all others very short. Then it is impossible for us to have it inscribed in a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have two smallest (closed) balls $B_r(a)$ and $B_r(b)$ containing the points. Then consider $c = \frac{a + b}{2}$.

Let us note that for every point $e$, we see that $d(c, e) \leq \max(d(a, e), d(b, e))$. In particular, when $a \neq b$, we have $d(c, e) < \max(d(a, e), d(b, e))$.

This is a basic fact of plane geometry (since $a, b, c$ are colinear, $a, b, c, e$ are coplanar).

Edit: let us elaborate on this. Since $a, b, c, e$ are coplanar and $a \neq b$, we give coordinates to the plane and WLOG set $a = (-1, 0)$, $b = (1, 0)$, $e = (x, y)$. Then $c = (0, 0)$. Now since $-1/2 < 1/2$ we either have that $x > -1/2$ or $x < 1/2$. WLOG, suppose $x < 1/2$. Then $d(c, e)^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $d(b, e)^2 = (1 - x)^2 + y^2 = x^2 + (1 - 2x) + y^2$. Since $x < 1/2$, we have $1 - 2x > 0$. So clearly, $d(c, e)^2 < d(b, e)^2$ and thus $d(c, e) < d(b, e)$.

It follows that for every point $x \in A$, we have $d(c, x) < r$. Therefore, we have $r' := \max\limits_{x \in A} d(c, x) < r$ since $A$ is finite. So we can form a smaller ball $B_{r'}(c)$ which contains all the points in $A$.

Comment: For my taste I could use a little elaboration of your second paragraph, but I like the solution.  $+1$.

Comment: @RobertShore I have provided some elaboration for you.

Comment: @Leon The case where $x > -1/2$ is totally analogous to the case where $x < 1/2$.

Comment: @MarkSaving yes, I understand, thank you so much for your help! +1

Comment: @MarkSaving Just a comment, your solution relies on the fact that $A$ has **finite** elements. But, in general, I think that the problem holds true for $A$ having **infinite** elements.

Comment: @Leon It is possible to extend this proof to work for infinite $A$. To do so, you must prove that there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $e \in A$, $d(c, e) \leq \max(d(a, e), d(b, e)) - \epsilon$. This can be done by slightly modifying the proof above and using the fact that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: @MarkSaving wao, you are absolutely right! such $\epsilon$ can be constructed by Parallelogram law. Many thanks!

Comment: A comment for other readers: $||e-c||\leq \frac{1}{2}(||e-a||+||e-b||)\leq \max(||e-a||, ||e-b||)$ and this inequality holds true for a general normed space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the radius of a smallest ball containing A.

Consider the intersection $S := \bigcap_{a \in A} B_r(a)$, where $B_r(a)$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ with center $a$. Then $S$ is non-empty as it contains the center of any ball of smallest radius containing $S$. Actually for any point $s \in S$, $A \subseteq B_r(s)$. Hence we want to prove that $S$ contains only one point.

Firstly, notice that the interior of $S$ must be empty: if $x$ is in the interior of $S$, then $d(x,a) < r$ for any $a \in A$, contradicting the minimality of $r$.

Secondly, $S$ is convex (as an intersection of convex set).

Now assume $S$ contains two distinct points $p$ and $q$, by convexity it contains the segment $[p,q]$. Let $t$ be a point in the interior of $[p,q]$ (for instance its middle point). Because $t$ is not in the interior of $S$, there is point $a \in A$ such that $d(t,a) = r$. Let the segment $[p',q']$ be the intersection of $B_r(a)$ and the line $pq$. Because $p$ and $q$ are in $B_r(a)$, $[p,q]$ is contained in $[p',q']$, so $t \in [p',q']$. But then, $p'$, $q'$ and $t$ are three distinct points in the intersection of the sphere $S_r(a)$ and the line $pq$, contradiction (a sphere and a line can have at most 2 common points).

Comment: yeah, thank you so much for your help! The idea is indeed amazing! According to me, the last sentences are not very clear: "Because $A$ is finite,.... more than twice, contradiction." Can you give some more explanations?

Comment: Original argument : Now assume $S$ contains two distinct points $p$ and $q$, by convexity it contains the segment $[p,q]$. For each point $t$ in that segment, because $t$ is not in the interior of $S$, there is point $a \in A$ such that $d(t,a) = r$. Because $A$ is finite, there must be some $a \in A$ with infinitely many such $t$. Hence, the line $pq$ intersects the sphere $S_r(a)$ more than twice, contradiction.

Comment: Explanation: so we can build a map $\phi : [p,q] \to A$ where $t \in S_r(\phi(t))$. The domain is infinite, and the codomain is finite, by pigeonhole principle there is some $a \in A$ with $\phi^-1(a)$ infinite. I am updating the answer with another argument that works when $A$ is infinite.

Comment: yeah thank you so much, I got the full idea now. Just a suggestion, I think that  you should write "$p', q'$ and $t'$ are three **distinct** points" since $t$ is an interior point of $[p,q]\subset [p', q']$.

Comment: Just a comment for other readers, @Guyslain exploited the fact that "the intersection of a sphere and a line can have at most two common points" and this fact only holds true in **strictly convex** space. +1 for Guyslain.

Comment: Yes indeed. I added the "distinct".

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose a slightly general solution (Actually, this is an idea of my friend)

**Problem.** Let $A$ be a **bounded** set of (potentially infinite) points in a **Hilbert** space $V$. Then the closed ball with smallest radius containing $A$ is unique.

Let $B(a, R)$ and $B(b, R)$ be two smallest-radius closed balls containing $A$ such that $a\neq b$. The boundedness  of $A$ ensures the existence of the smallest ball. Let $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$. We now want to construct a new closed ball $B(c, R')$ with $R'<R$, thus obtain a contradiction.

Since $V$ is Hilbertian, then the [Parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) can be applied, i.e.
$$||x-c||^2=\frac{1}{2}(||x-a||^2+||x-b||^2)-||c-a||^2\leq R^2-\varepsilon^2,$$
where $x\in A\subset B(a,R)\cap B(b, R)$ and $\varepsilon:=||c-a||>0$.
Thus,
$$R':=\sup_{x\in A} ||x-c||\leq \sqrt{R^2-\varepsilon^2}<R.$$

Then $B(c, R')$ is a smaller ball containing $A$. We get the contradiction.

The uniqueness has been proved.

---

**Further reading.**

- Note that the quantity $2\sqrt{R^2-\varepsilon^2}$ is exactly the [generalized diameter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedDiameter.html) of the set $B(a,R)\cap B(b, R)$.
- Every Hilbert space is [strictly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space), thus implies $$||x-c||<\frac{1}{2}(||x-a||+||x-b||)\leq \max(||x-a||, ||x-b||)$$ as stated by MarkSaving in above answer.
- Every Banach space satisfying the Parallelogram law is Hilbertian.
- Note that the uniqueness of the smallest ball does not hold any more if $V$ is not a strictly convex space, e.g. $\mathbb R^2$ with $\ell^\infty$-norm, even in the case that $A$ contains only two points.
- 24th July, 2021: I found a proof [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-information-and-systems/volume-6/issue-2/On-the-Smallest-Enclosing-Balls/cis/1175791057.full)